# Omni-Channel Beta: Cases being assigned beyond agent capacity

Tags: omnichannel

I'm working on setting up Omni-channel for my company. I want to cases to be automatically assigned to our agents and allow agents to have 4 cases in progress at a time. (So I have set the agents' capacity to 4, and set each case equal to 1 unit of capacity). Theoretically, this should mean only 4 cases are pushed to an agent at a time; however, omni-channel is currently ignoring my capacity of 4, assigning a limitless number of cases to the same agent.

(I've checked my profiles and queue access but can find no inconsistencies.)

I realize Omni-channel is still is in beta, but I was wondering if anyone had found a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem I was running into. I knew that Omni-Channels created a work item for every case that was assigned to an agent. However, I did not realize that the status of the work item and the status of the case are not equivalently matched.

Where the status of the case is manually updated to “closed” once an agent is finished with a case, the status of a work item is automatically updated to “closed” as soon as the case window in the console is closed (regardless of case status).

Since agent capacity is determined by work items rather than cases, this means that in order to limit agents to 4 cases at a time the agent must keep all in-progress cases open in their console windows. Only when they are done working on a case should they update the case status and close the window (automatically updating the work item status, and allowing the agent to receive another assignment).